# How do I remove default class from textarea in a SilverStripe form

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe I have a textarea in a form that is created from a controller.

I would like to remove the default class `class="textarea"` from the generated HTML and instead use the class `class="form_control"`.

How do I remove and add a class on a form field such as a `TextareField`?

**TextareaField creation**

```php
$message = new TextareaField('Message', 'Message');     
$message->addExtraClass('form-control');
$message->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Message (required)');    
$message->setAttribute('rows', '5');
$message->setAttribute('cols', '25');
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<div id="Message" class="field textarea rounded">
    <label class="left" for="Form_Form_Message">Message</label>
    <div class="middleColumn">
        <textarea id="Form_Form_Message" class="textarea" cols="20" rows="5" name="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all the classes from the TextareaField you can use the `setAttribute` function with a first parameter of  `'class'` and a second parameter containing the classes you want to put in:

```php
$message->setAttribute('class', 'form_control');
```

Otherwise if you are happy for the `'textarea'` class to remain you could add additional classes using the `addExtraClass` function:

```php
$email->addExtraClass('form_control');
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the simplest way is to override the template.

copy `/framework/templates/forms/TextareaField.ss` to your `mysite` folder and add each required attribute manually, using `$getAttribute()` (instead of relying on `$AttributesHtml`):

```
<textarea class="form_control" cols="$getAttribute('cols')">$Value</textarea>
```